# Finding emails by subject name with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, imaplib

I'm trying to pull emails in my inbox with a certain subject name by using the following code:

```
import imapclient
import pprint
imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap-mail.outlook.com',ssl=True)
imapObj.login('personalemail@outlook.com','strongpassword')
imapObj.select_folder('INBOX',readonly=True)
imapObj.search('SUBJECT Broker Dealer Fails Report – NY')
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-d172a6d61d89> in <module>
      1 imapObj.select_folder('INBOX',readonly=True)
----> 2 imapObj.search('SUBJECT Broker Dealer Fails Report – NY')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py in search(self, criteria, charset)
    954 
    955         """
--> 956         return self._search(criteria, charset)
    957 
    958     @require_capability('X-GM-EXT-1')

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py in _search(self, criteria, charset)
    977         if charset:
    978             args.extend([b'CHARSET', to_bytes(charset)])
--> 979         args.extend(_normalise_search_criteria(criteria, charset))
    980 
    981         try:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py in _normalise_search_criteria(criteria, charset)
   1614 
   1615     if isinstance(criteria, (text_type, binary_type)):
-> 1616         return [to_bytes(criteria, charset)]
   1617 
   1618     out = []

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imapclient\util.py in to_bytes(s, charset)
     28 def to_bytes(s, charset='ascii'):
     29     if isinstance(s, text_type):
---> 30         return s.encode(charset)
     31     return s
     32 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried different combinations of using lists in the parenthesis ([]), using '' and "" for the name of the subject.

Comment: You’ll need quotes around the subject ‘SUBJECT “Whatever and ever”’.  What error do you get there?  Also, if that’s an em dash (not an ASCII -), you’ll need to either not search for it, or use charset=“UTF-8”.  You may need to read the documents about how to do non-ASCII searches.

Answer (score 0):

Subject should start with "Subject:" try this and see if it works